# Unit test is failing with preact and Vite with "Cannot read property '__H' of undefined"

Tags: vite, preact, vitest

I am using preact with Vite.The component is rendering perfectly in browser but the unit test case is giving error like this

error:
name: "TypeError"
message: "Cannot read property '__H' of undefined"

Component.jsx

```
export const component= (props) => {
  const allItems = props.options;

  const [totalCost, setTotalCost] = useState(0);
  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
    new Array(allItems.length).fill(false)
  );
.....
}
```

Test file imports:

```
import { component } from '../../../Component';
```

Comment: This usually indicates that you're loading multiple copies of Preact at once, which will not work as Preact needs to be a singleton. See https://github.com/preactjs/preact/issues/4035

Comment: I am clueless that whee should I check this multiple copies. In .jsx file and .js (test) file I have imported once as required.

Comment: What test framework are you using? It's likely injecting multiple copies.